# ID function for objects and references

Tags: python, object, reference

Let's make x pointing to list [1,2,3] and obtain the id function (twice):

```
x=[1,2,3]

id(x), id([1,2,3])
(208085256L, 208123976L)

id(x), id([1,2,3])
(208085256L, 208124168L)
```

We say that every object that is created is given a number that uniquely identifies it.

As far I understand x is the pointer/reference and [1,2,3] is the object. That is the ID of the pointer (x) is 208085256L and it stays the same in the second observation. But why does the ID of the object [1,2,3] change then, when it is said that every object that is created is given a number that uniquely identifies it. Is my reasoning wrong?

Or should I rather understand the whole thing the way that the ID of the reference x (208085256L) "points" to object [1,2,3] and that I can ignore the second ID?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[1, 2, 3]` creates a new list object each time it is evaluated.

In total, your code sample creates three lists.

`x` is a name for the first one.